# How historically accurate Is this replica "15th century hand and a half" sword?

Tags: middle-ages, sword

Sorry, not a plug, but [this sword](https://www.themedievalstore.com/collections/two-handed-medieval-swords/products/15th-century-hand-and-a-half-sword) at this shop called The Medieval Store has a 15th century hand and a half sword and I am curious the historical significance of it. What makes it 15th century? Can anyone explain?

Comment: Looks like nice replica of a "Schwert zu anderthalb Hand", aka Bastardsword, "Anderthalbhänder". At these times largely a ceremonial weapon used in ordeals or together with the fencing feather as sports instrument. Blade should ~90cm (must unsheath it ;-), weight ~900 grams, center of gravity 2-3 cm before the hilt and this makes a nice weapon. Oh, and no stainless steel pls. !

Comment: Carbon steel - a no go ! :-) I'm not writing an answer because all my sources are in German. But i am sure a friendly colleague will show up soon. But search for "Sempach Schwert" (Battle of Sempach) can be an entry point.

Comment: They probably labelled it that purely because the bastard sword (aka hand and a half sword) originated in the 15th century. Those swords I believe averaged around 40" or longer blades, so this is actually a bit short.

Comment: If genuinely interested, you might look for translations of the fencing manuscripts of these guys https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Liechtenauer or https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Talhoffer

Comment: I LOVE the customer review: "This is the only battle-ready sword I’ll ever need to purchase."

Comment: You might compare it with [this example in the Wallace Collection](https://wallacelive.wallacecollection.org:443/eMP/eMuseumPlus?service=ExternalInterface&module=collection&objectId=60969&viewType=detailView) (item No A476), or [this one in the V&A collection](http://collections.vam.ac.uk/item/O97450/hand-and-a-unknown/) (museum No 
M.603-1927).

Comment: Why no stainless steel?